# Three-way ANOVA with contrasts in Stata

Tags: anova, stata

I'm analyzing some data right now and I have several planned comparisons I want to check.  There is one continuous response variable (response) and 3 categorical factor variables (profile, drug, disease).  Each factor variable (profile, drug, disease) has 2 levels (1,2).

I performed an ANOVA in Stata with the following command:

```
anova response i.profile##i.drug##i.disease
```

This works fine.

When I want to test my specific conditions and try to use the test command, I enter:

```
test i1.profile#i1.drug#i1.disease = i2.profile#i1.drug#i1.disease
```

It gives me this error:  "Constraint 1 dropped", and doesn't give me any p-value as output.

However, if instead I run:

```
anova response i.profile#i.drug#i.disease
```

and then do

```
test i1.profile#i1.drug#i1.disease = i2.profile#i1.drug#i1.disease
```

I get the desired result.  Is this the correct way to do this?  Why is Stata dropping a constraint (and what constraint)?

I don't care about making comparisons like 1.profile vs 2.profile, just among specific combinations of profile, drug, and disease.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The _constraint_ is just the test. Stata complains when there are redundant or inconsistent test specifications. Read **[R]test**, which has a few examples on this.